# If-else statement in just one line for simple text

Tags: php, if-statement, text, ternary-operator

I want to write some text `Year: X | percentage: $percentage%`, where `X` is based on the value contained in `$year`.

`$year` can be `2010`, `2011`... but also `0`. In this case, we have to write the word `"All"`; otherwise, the year itself.

```
Year: 2011 | percentage: 2%    // case $year not 0
Year: All | percentage: 2%     // case $year == 0
```

This code seems very long for what is required:

```
echo "year: ";
if ($year==0)
     echo "All";
else
     echo $year;

echo " | Percentage: $percentage%";
```

So I wonder: how can we make this code shorter and clearer?

<sub>Note I posted my own answer because I wanted to share the way I found after spending some time working on it. Anyway, I see there are other ones that look quite good.</sub>

Comment: I'd use brackets and make it longer and easier to read. The answer below is incredibly hard to read.

Comment: You should have posted your 'answer' in your original question and asked for other ways of doing what you were looking at doing. Your answer is the least readable.

Comment: @mickmackusa aren't there any better canonical for ternary operators? The answer there is not very generic

Comment: There will be tens of duplicates between SO's birth and the date of your question.  If you find a better one, I am happy to change the dupe or add it to the list.

Comment: @mickmackusa there is no need for the duplicate to be older than mine, just one that is better.

Comment: @fed  I agree.  My offer stands.  Find a better one and I'll fix it up. On the other hand, do we actually need one hunder signposts for this operation?  Anyhow, I am busy down a rabbit hole -- whistle blowing the `echo sprintf()` antipattern. `SELECT a.Id as [Post Link], a.CreationDate
FROM Posts a
INNER JOIN posts q ON q.id = a.parentid
WHERE q.tags LIKE '%<##tag?php##>%'
  AND a.PostTypeId = 2
  AND LEN(a.Body) < 300
  AND a.Body LIKE '%echo sprintf(%'
  ORDER BY a.CreationDate ASC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry if this doesnt work (cant test it right now) but in C (which is somewhat similar to php) you can negate numbers directly, i belive you could also use:

```
echo "Year: ". (!$year ? "All" : $year) ." | Percentage: $percentage%";
```

Comment: It worked, @Kyborek! I think it is a very nice way of showing it. In fact, could also be writen like `($year ? $year:'All')`, as someone exposed in a comment above.

Comment: We can meta think your sentence "no negation == afirming"! : )

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
echo ( condition ? "if condition true" : "otherwise")
```

For this specific case:

```
echo "Year: ". ((0==$year) ? "All" : $year) ." | Percentage: $percentage%";
```

Comment: ($year ? $year:'All') would make it even shorter

Answer (score 2):

Might not be a direct answer to you questions, but IMHO you should do something like:

```
$renderedYear = $year;
if ($year == 0) {
    $renderedYear = 'All';
}

echo 'Year: ' . $renderedYear . ' | Percentage: ' . $percentage . '%';
```

Always prefer readability over shortness of code. Pixels on screen are waaaay cheaper than debugging time.

Also instead of concatenating you may want to use `*printf`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but as long as the OP doesn't need to reuse $year

Comment: Yeah that's a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, @PeeHaa, looks interesting although I was looking for a one-line solution. Anyway it is very clear in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would style it using `sprintf()` as it's far easier to read.

```
echo sprintf("year: %s | Percentage: %s %%", ($year == 0) ? "All" : $year, $percentage);
```

Comment: I was going to recommend the same. However, don't use `echo sprintf` when you have `printf` for the purpose :) (also, since you commented on the ease of reading, params might be easier to understand on separate lines - and further, `===` instead of `==`)

Comment: Updated with printf. The use of `===` is up to the OP.

Comment: printf replaces the combination of echo + sprintf, now you replaced only sprintf.

Comment: moved back to using sprint as I originally intended it.

Comment: This is a way I find interesting. I will take a look, thanks.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.